# How to get function stack trace for any function?

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, stack-trace

For example, I have the following code:

```
def m1(num):
    pass


def m2(num):
    pass


def foo(num):
    m2(num)


def foo2(num):
    foo(num)
    m1(num)

def main():
    foo2(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there a way to get call list for each function? For example, for this example I want to get the following dict:

```
main: foo2
foo2: foo, m1
foo: m2
m2: 
m1:
```

I know only one way to complete my task. It is to use `globals()` and then parse source code. But it seems is very ugly.

Comment: What you're looking to build is not a stack trace, but a call graph—sort of an upside-down stack trace.

Comment: Also, "I know only one way to complete my task. It is to use `globals()` and then parse source code." How do you think parsing source code would help? I can't see any solution where that would be useful. But if you can show that, I'll bet I could show you how to replace the parsing with something different.

Comment: @abarnert, globals()["__file__"] is path of our file. I think, that we can do something like that: `f = open("globals()["__file__"]");` and then parse it.

Comment: Well, `globals()["__file__"]` gets you the exact same thing as just `__file__`, so `globals` isn't helping there… Also, you can use `inspect.getsource` to read source. Meanwhile, what would you _do_ with the data once you parse it? You can use the `ast` module to create a parsed tree out of it, but then what? Are you just looking to create a _static_ call graph—all the functions referenced in `main`'s body—rather than a _dynamic_ one—all the functions called during an actual run of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know only one way to complete my task. It is to use `globals()` and then parse source code. But it seems is very ugly.

I'm not sure what you think parsing source code would do for you here.

---

If you want to build a dynamic call graph, what you want to do is decorate each function—replace it with a wrapper that does some extra stuff before or after calling the real function. For example:

```
def wrapper(func):
    @functools.wraps
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff to update call graph
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

g = globals()
for name, value in g.items():
    if callable(value):
        g[name] = wrapper(value)
```

Or, maybe more simply (and more flexibly), you might want to use the [`bdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) debugger framework to step through your program and just record the `user_call` instances.

---

If you want to build a *static* call graph, then obviously that comes from the source, but there's no reason to parse it yourself when Python comes with the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module to do it for you. (You can use [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) to get the source code to parse.)

Comment: is it right, that wrapper does not return anything? I have just an error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Comment: @Denis: Sorry, yeah, you need to `return wrap`. Fixed. This is just a bog-standard [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)—even if you aren't using it like one (putting `@wrapper` before each `def` statement) you still define it the same way.

Comment: I am sorry, but do You test this code? I get error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__module__'` on line `foo2(1)`. I try fix it, but I have no success.